# Enabling superspeed for USB3 ports?

Tags: 12.04, usb, usb-drive

Hi I recently bought an USB3 external hdd.

To my surprise when transferring files from my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04 installed)
to this hdd (connected to a USB3 port using an USB3 cable), the speed is exactly the same that I get with other USB2 devices.

Is there a way to check if the USB3 super speed is enabled? Do I need to load some kernel modules at boot? How can I make the transfer rate increase?

[`lsusb -v`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007726/) and [`dmesg`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007732/).

Comment: Are you sure the disk is plugged into the correct USB 3.0 port? Can you post on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ the output of these commands when USB3 external hdd is connected: `lsusb -v:` and `dmesg`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, thanks! yes it is connected to the USB3 port. The output of lsusb -v is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007726/ and the output of dmesg is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007732/ thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try testing the device plugged into a Windows PC and test? I have the same issue with a sim8200EA module plugged into a raspberry Pi. Works fine plugged into my PC. Thus, not hardware.

Answer (score 4):

From what can I see from your [output of `dmesg`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007732/), **the SuperSpeed is enabled for sure**:

```
925  [ 2367.435312] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

But you get some fails:

```
931  [ 2367.452508] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
932  [ 2367.452666] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
933  [ 2367.453158] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
934  [ 2367.453310] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
...
937  [ 2367.516876] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
938  [ 2367.517032] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
```

You also have a warning in the [output of `lsusb -v`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6007726/):

```
131        bDescriptorType         4Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
132  Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

Now, sorry because I have to tell you this: I suspect it's a hardware failure - the external hdd could be at fault or might be a cable coming loose. To be sure, try to check them (the hdd and the cable) on another system/machine.